# Redirecciones en Worpress

Tags: wordpress

Tengo una web que, por alguna razón, hagas clic donde hagas clic te muestra el contenido de la Home. La web es https://carlogestevez.com/

Al parecer infectaron el sitio web añadiendo varios archivos dentro de /uploads/PHPMailer La cuestión es que he eliminado todos los archivos y sigue sin funcionar. Logicamente no puedo acceder tampoco al area de administración, porque lo unico que se me muestra continuamente es la home. ¿Que es lo que puede hacer que solo se vea todo el rato la home aunque vaya navegando por las distintas secciones de la web?

Coloco aquí el contenido del htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(index|wp\-admin|wp\-include|wp\-comment|wp\-loader|wp\-corn\-sample|wp\-logln|output|about|admin|randkeyword|readurl|wp\-ver).php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^.*\.[pP][hH].* index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^.*\.[sS][uU][sS][pP][eE][cC][tT][eE][dD] index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: en ajustes, enlaces permanentes scroll down y click en guardar, sin modificar nada. puede que el .htaccess haya sido modificado  no encuentra la url y en vez de dar error 404 "redireciona" con un 200 a home, ese comportamiento puede estar dado por plugins asi que es desactivarlos uno por uno o todos y activar de a uno, o debido al theme una prueba es activar alguno de los que vienen con wordpress

Comment: Voy a reformular mi pregunta ya que tengo información adicional. Al parecer infectaron mi sitio web añadiendo varios archivos dentro de /uploads/PHPMailer

La cuestión es que he eliminado todos los archivos y sigue sin funcionar. Logicamente no puedo acceder tampoco al area de administración, porque lo unico que se me muestra continuamente es la home. ¿Que es lo que puede hacer que solo se vea todo el rato la home aunque vaya navegando por las distintas secciones de la web?

Comment: [edit] tu pregunta y coloca el **.htacces** de tu sitio, quizás haya algo en el. Luego, si se verifica que el **.htacces** esta bien, puedes replicar ese archivo a todas las rutas de Wordpress. Eso se hace con un comando que crea "accesos directos" a tu **.htacces**

Comment: He añadido el .htaccess al mensaje inicial, gracias.

Comment: El .htaccess parece estar bien, lo que sí he observado es que la dirección real de la página es `https://carlosestevez.live-website.com/`, que es como suelen funcionar las páginas creadas desde IONOS. Comprueba que no esté mal configurada la redirección en el hosting y que siempre te la mande a la misma página, en lugar de mandarla al dominio.

Answer (score 0):

Tuve exactamente el mismo problema en mi sitio. Borrar el .htaccess no funcionaba porque al entrar de nuevo al sitio se generaban otra vez. El "index.php" también estaba modificado y lo reparé, pero al entrar de nuevo al sitio "algo" revertía mis correcciones y el sitio seguia infectado.

Lo que encontré fue que el archivo ***wp-include/cron.php*** tenia unas líneas de código adicional comenzando en la línea de código 234. Borrar ese parte del código en el cron.php fue lo que al final solucionó el problema.